# New to Tensorflow - trying to repurpose an MNIST multilayer network to a calculator

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

Could someone help or guide me through what I should do better in order for this to work?

I changed the number of inputs to 2 and generated some random data, "x1" and "x2" (one number to be added to another). The idea is to use variables "add" and "mul" as the real output and base the cost (variable "Y") off of that, but I'm having trouble manipulating the data so it inputs properly.

I tried to make another variable with

x = tf.Variable([100 * np.random.random_sample([100]), 100 * np.random.random_sample([100]))

and a few other alternative ways, but that caused errors. Also, if there's anything else wrong in my code, please critique it! Anything helps.

Thank you.

```
'''
A Recurrent Neural Network implementation example using TensorFlow Library.

Author: *********
'''

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.models.rnn import rnn, rnn_cell
# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# Parameters
training_iters = 1000
n_epochs       = 1000
batch_size     = 128
display_step   = 100
learning_rate  = 0.001

n_observations = 100
n_input        = 2   # Input data (Num + Num)
n_steps        = 28  # timesteps
n_hidden_1     = 256 # 1st layer number of features
n_hidden_2     = 256 # 2nd layer number of features
n_classes      = 1   # Output

X  = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input])
X1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
X2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
Y  = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

# Random input data
x1 = 100 * np.random.random_sample([100,])
x2 = 100 * np.random.random_sample([100,])

add = tf.add(x1, x2)
mul = tf.mul(X1, X2)

weights = {
    'hidden1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input,    n_hidden_1])),
    #'hidden2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2])),
    'out':     tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1,  n_classes]))
}

biases = {
    'hidden1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
    #'hidden2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2])),
    'out':     tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}

def RNN(_X1, _weights, _biases):

    # Layer 1.1
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(_X1, weights['hidden1']), biases['hidden1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
    # Layer 1.2
    # layer_1_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(_X2, weights['hidden2']), biases['hidden2'])
    # layer_1_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1_2)
    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_2   = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['out']), biases['out'])

    output    = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)

    return output

pred         = RNN(X1, weights, biases)
cost         = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(pred - Y, 2)) / (n_observations - 1)
optimizer    = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost) # Adam Optimizer
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(Y,1))

init     = tf.initialize_all_variables()
# initData = tf.initialize_variables(x1.all(), x2.all())

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Here we tell tensorflow that we want to initialize all
    # the variables in the graph so we can use them
    sess.run(init)

    # Fit all training data
    prev_training_cost = 0.0

    for epoch_i in range(n_epochs) :
        for (_x1) in x1:
            for (_x2) in x2:
                print("Input 1:")
                print(_x1)
                print("Input 2:")
                print(_x2)
                print("Add function: ")
                print(sess.run(add, feed_dict={X1: x1, X2: x2}))
                y =   sess.run(add, feed_dict={X1: x1, X2: x2})
                print(y)
                sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: x, Y: y})


        training_cost = sess.run(
            cost, feed_dict={X: xs, Y: ys})
        print(training_cost)

        if epoch_i % 20 == 0:
            ax.plot(X1, X2, pred.eval(
                feed_dict={X1: x1, X2: x2}, session=sess),
                    'k', alpha=epoch_i / n_epochs)
            fig.show()
            plt.draw()

        # Allow the training to quit if we've reached a minimum
        if np.abs(prev_training_cost - training_cost) < 0.000001:
            break
        prev_training_cost = training_cost
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So are you training a feed forward network or a recurrent neural network?

The code you write within RNN() remind me of a simple neural network (feedforward network). Yet your tittle says you are working on RNN's

You might find [this](http://robromijnders.github.io/LSTM_mult/) implementation interesting. Like you, it generates vectors of integers and uses an RNN to do the addition